# How to add docker-volume to docker-compose in a project?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I have an API written in Rust with a PostgreSQL database. I store project data in docker containers, using docker-compose I run it. There was a need to use docker-volume but I do not quite understand how to combine the two docker technologies.

All my understanding stops at creating some entity through "docker volume create". It is not clear how to link the project with this entity. As I understand it, you need to add volume to the .env file, but after trying, the project stopped starting and I had to roll back the version. In docker compose I wrote volume;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Dm9.png)
But after the next launch, the program gives me an error: service "postgres" refers to undefined volume pg_database: invalid compose project.